# Creating a version to host only proposed infrastructure, that is reconciled and posted when the work is completed?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase

I have come across a scenario where I have been asked to find a way to create a version that stems off of a DEFAULT version of ArcGIS Server and hosts only proposed infrastructure data.  This is being done so that there is a way to visualize the proposed infrastructure with the current infrastructure and so we can be ahead of the game when it comes to updating the actual constructed layers.  I am trying to determine whether or not this is possible and if it is, how can this be done without impacting any other data hosted on the server?

I have come Phased Project versions, but I am unsure as to how the work flow would be implemented and whether or not it would work for what I am trying to do with what we already have built:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/version-scenarios.htm#GUID-E09C2189-85FC-42AD-8DCA-2CC28B621CAF

Comment: Of course this is possible (it's in the documentation, after all), but the meaning of "without impacting any other data" is undefined.  As with most things GIS, "Try it out and see if it meets your criteria" is going to be more useful than a bunch of guesses from the peanut gallery.